# What are the steps to successfully run Ranch on windows?

Tags: windows, erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, ranch

Please what steps do we need to take to get Ranch working successfully on windows?

There is a very instructive set of examples in a great blog series which i am trying to follow here:

http://dbeck.github.io/Using-Ranch-From-Elixir/

http://dbeck.github.io/simple-TCP-message-performance-in-Elixir/

It however requires that we use the Ranch Erlang Lib.

Getting this to work on windows has been a pain so far:

mix.deps.compile fails

```
C:\Elixir\tcp_eval>mix deps.update --all
Running dependency resolution
Dependency resolution completed successfully
  ranch: v1.1.0

C:\Elixir\tcp_eval>mix deps.compile
==> ranch
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - SRC
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
File not found - SRC/
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
Access denied - EBIN
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -NAME
 APP    ranch.app.src
```

Comment: It looks like the makefile for Ranch runs `find` and expects it to be the Unix version, but it gets the Windows version instead, which actually is more like `grep`.

Comment: i will try it again in the msys64 environment

Comment: @|peer-stritzinger seen you edit. If we can get Ranch to run on windows, then we may apply same or similar to other erlang libs that use erlang.mk for example. So in a sense, it is also an erlang related post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from here:

https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk/issues/294#issuecomment-147379818

I was able to get Ranch working on windows.

1) install the **msys2 environment**

2) run mix from within the MSYS2 environment

**EDIT: Doing this via rebar**

```
D:\Elixir\tcp_eval>rebar
'rebar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Elixir\tcp_eval>rebar3
Rebar3 is a tool for working with Erlang projects.


Usage: rebar [-h] [-v] [<task>]

  -h, --help     Print this help.
  -v, --version  Show version information.
  <task>         Task to run.


Several tasks are available:

as                Higher order provider for running multiple tasks in a sequence as a certain profiles.
clean             Remove compiled beam files from apps.
compile           Compile apps .app.src and .erl files.
cover             Perform coverage analysis.
ct                Run Common Tests.
deps              List dependencies
dialyzer          Run the Dialyzer analyzer on the project.
do                Higher order provider for running multiple tasks in a sequence.
edoc              Generate documentation using edoc.
escriptize        Generate escript archive.
eunit             Run EUnit Tests.
help              Display a list of tasks or help for a given task or subtask.
new               Create new project from templates.
path              Print paths to build dirs in current profile.
pkgs              List available packages.
release           Build release of project.
relup             Create relup of releases.
report            Provide a crash report to be sent to the rebar3 issues page.
shell             Run shell with project apps and deps in path.
tar               Tar archive of release built of project.
tree              Print dependency tree.
unlock            Unlock dependencies.
update            Update package index.
upgrade           Upgrade dependencies.
version           Print version for rebar and current Erlang.
xref              Run cross reference analysis.

plugins <task>:
  list           List local and global plugins for this project
  upgrade        Upgrade plugins

unstable <task>:
  install        Extract libs from rebar3 escript along with a run script.
  upgrade        Download latest rebar3 escript and extract.

Run 'rebar3 help <TASK>' for details.

D:\Elixir\tcp_eval>
```

Looking at Hex.pm, I decided to install ***rebar3***, this works/integrates well with mix.

following http://theburningmonk.com/2014/08/getting-started-with-rebar-on-windows/ we can get ***rebar3*** working on windows

but this still does not work:

```
D:\Elixir\tcp_eval>mix deps.compile
==> ranch
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
==> tcp_eval
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :ranch, "make" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ranch",

D:\Elixir\tcp_eval>
```

Comment: You should be able to get that working without having to use Msys.  Do you have rebar installed?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci see this:

`D:\Elixir\tcp_eval>mix deps.compile
==> ranch
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
==> tcp_eval
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :ranch, "make" command failed.`

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci even after installing rebar, still have no default "make" on windows

Comment: There wouldn't be a default "make" on Windows.  Either you need to install gnu make or Visual Studio make (which is actually called nmake if memory serves) or something else.  Plus it needs to be added to the path as well.

Comment: Type "rebar" (minus the double quotes) from a command prompt.  Post what you get as an edit on your question.  Rebar needs to be in your path and it needs to work correctly to get Ranch going.

Comment: Now do the same thing with "make".  If you don't have _make_, I'd say the simplest way to get it is here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Comment: got make working, now it seems there is an issue with erlang.mk

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci some new info https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk/issues/294#issuecomment-165179845